# Filtering an array with condition in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter an array  to output all the children who will be on holidays within a date range (i.e 14-11-2016 till 18-11-2016) in PHP.

I get the following data in an array and I do not have any control on creation of the data.

```
[{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"22-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"14-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"16-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"14-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"16-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"}]
```

I need to output data for only the ones whose "holiday" are >= 14-11-2016 and <= 18-11-2016.

I have tried the following logic but it does not return anything

```
function filterArray($value)
{
  return ($value > '14-11-2016');
}

$filteredArray = array_filter($fullArray, 'filterArray');

foreach($filteredArray as $k => $v)
{
 echo "$k = $v";
}
```

Comment: Use the `DateTime` class to parse the date. Afterwards compare the `DateTime` object you previously created so that it belongs on the date range you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are sure that 'holiday' field contains correct data, then you can use this code:

```
$fullArray = json_decode( '[{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"22-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"14-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"16-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"14-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"16-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"}]', true );


//I need to output data for only the ones whose "holiday" are >= 14-11-2016 and <= 18-11-2016.


function filterArray($value)
{
        static $from  = 20161114;
        static $until = 20161118;

        // parse the date and convert it to an int.    
        $v = new \DateTime( $value['holiday'] );
        $v = (int)$v->format('Ymd');

        // compare as integer
        return ($v >= $from && $v <= $until );
}

$filteredArray = array_filter($fullArray, 'filterArray');

foreach($filteredArray as $k => $v)
{
        var_dump($v); // prints sub-array
}
```

You can also compare DateTime objects:

```
//I need to output data for only the ones whose "holiday" are >= 14-11-2016 and <= 18-11-2016.

$from  = new \DateTime('2016-11-14');
$until = new \DateTime('2016-11-18');

function filterArray($value)
{
        global $from, $until;
        $v = new \DateTime( $value['holiday'] );
        return ($v >= $from && $v <= $until );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function filterArray($value)
{
  return (strtotime('18-11-2016') >= strtotime($value["holiday"])) && (strtotime($value["holiday"]) >= strtotime('14-11-2016'));
}
$string = '[{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"22-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"14-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"16-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"14-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"16-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"}]';

$fullArray = json_decode($string, true);
$filteredArray = array_filter($fullArray, 'filterArray');

foreach($filteredArray as $k => $v)
{
 echo "$k = ". $v['holiday'] ." - ".$v['name']."<br/>";
}
```

And using closures from PHP 5.3 and upper versions:

```
$from = strtotime('14-11-2016');
$to = strtotime('18-11-2016');
$string = '[{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"22-11-2016","name":"Josh Stevens"},{"holiday":"14-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"16-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Naomi Christ"},{"holiday":"14-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"15-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"16-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"},{"holiday":"17-11-2016","name":"Jasmine Auger"}]';

$fullArray = json_decode($string, true);
$filteredArray = array_filter($fullArray, function($elem) use ($from, $to){
    $holidayTime = strtotime($elem['holiday']);
    return ($from <= $holidayTime) && ($holidayTime <= $to);
});
```